# How to encrypt the value from Entry for password with AES 256

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am doing Xamarin forms app. I am not sure what is the current nuget for Encryption AES 256 for xamarin Forms on VS2017.

I have the below XAML.

I need to encrypt the password with Encryption AES 256

```
XAML:
<StackLayout  Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,10,3,3" Padding="20,06,20,10">
   <Label Text="username" FontSize="23" Margin="5" />
   <Entry x:Name="usernameEntry" Placeholder="Enter your username" />
  <Label Text="Password" FontSize="23" Margin="5" />
 <Entry x:Name="passwordEntry" IsPassword="true" Placeholder="Enter your password"  />
 <Label x:Name="messageLabel" />
</StackLayout>
```

Code:
In MonoDroid is using different method. I like Xamarin Form because it handles both Android and iOS.
I am not sure is this correct in Xamarin form for getting the value from Entry for password:

```
  var pwd = passwordEntry.Text.ToString();
```

I need help on use AES 256 to encrypt this pwd.

Yor help is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think you need to encrypt the password, that is in general bad security. What are you trying to accomplish? If you are trying to ensure the password is secure while being transmitted to the server use HTTPS and certificate pinning. If you are trying to protect the password on the server for validation use a password hashing function such as PBKDF2.

Comment: This is the requirement from my customer. I need to send the username and pwd to the server via HttpClient Post. Say, they want this way, how this canbe done?

Comment: My knowledge in Security is not good.  If HTTPS is used, I dont have to encrypt the username and pwd and I do a http Post via HttpClient. If they want to encrypt Password for whatever reason, how do I do that?

Comment: You will need to download cert to each device to do that. I don't think it is practical but can be done. Is that acceptable?

Comment: You going to decrypt your password on server? Then both sides (mobile and server) have to have the same certificate. Another option is to use symmetric encryption with one key but I don't think it is a good idea.

Comment: @Zaph, Yuri  Thank u all.  have educated the client. No encryption is needed in https.

Answer (score 0):

Just use HTTPS, everything is encrypted, even the URL query string.

Pin the certificate and there is no chance of MITM attacks and if the server supports TLS 1.2 and perfect forward secrecy a different encryption key is used for each session.